A problem with Timer.periodic and Timer.cancel
i have a little problem with Timer.periodic an cancel, i have function which takes information from an api each seconds it works well the problem is that i can't stop it when i want by using Timer.cancel. this is my error:Instance member 'cancel' can't be accessed using static access
 void checking() {
Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (check) {
  Future<void> recup() async {
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse('https://konamicash.com/verification_cron');
      var response = await http.get(url);
      print(response.statusCode);
      print('get no');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var reponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
        var message = reponse['situation'];
        print(message);
        print(reponse);
        if (message == 1) {Timer.cancel();

              },
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('erreur $e');
    }
  }

  recup();
});

}

you want "check.cancel()", not "Timer.cancel()".  Also, not sure why you're definiting a function inside the other function.

oooooooh my god i even didn't notice it i am ashaaaaaaaaaaamed, i will delete this post very soon, such A SHAME

By not saving a reference to the result of Timer.periodic that you can check for (or cancel) later, your code also falls into a typically problematic pattern where nothing prevents you from accidentally creating multiple, concurrent periodic timers.

your Timer callback is check so fix it by check.cancel() but it will only work in periodic function try this solution
1). Define Timer variable
Timer? timer

2). Assign timer with timer.periodic()
timer = Timer.periodic( 
  Duration(milliseconds : 500), (_) async {
     // Activity here
   }
)

now you will able to access timer (timer?.cancel()) from the other function and easy to read
